# How to center align

Tags: html, css

How to center align following html in such way that ':' should be at the center & should be listed below one another

```
<ul>

<li>
<label>Suomething 1 :</label> 
<span>Another 111111111111111111</span>
</li>

<li>
<label>Suomething 2222222222 :</label> 
<span>Another 2</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
label{
width:25%;
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
}
```

Edit:-added CSS

Comment: share your css, which you have already tried or using.

Comment: @matzone, using table is not an option. The above snippet is generated by a SF component.

Comment: May be my question wasn't clear enough. Correct answer was up voted only once. Exactly same answer were upvoted 6 times & downvoted 2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use table displays:

http://jsfiddle.net/5NarV/1

#### CSS

```
ul {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
}

label, span {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

label {
    text-align: right;
}

span {
    padding-left: 0.35em;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Suomething 1 :</label> 
        <span>Another 111111111111111111</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Suomething 2222222222 :</label> 
        <span>Another 2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I prefer Hiral's answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
label{width:170px;display:inline-block;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/WVrKF/)

Answer (score 1):

It works with this CSS:

```
li {
    display: block;
}
label {
    width:35%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:right;
    float:left;
}

span {
    width:65%;
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tVSte/

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SZKwq/)**

**css**

```
ul{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: this is not what he wants, he wants to align the text below on another keeping the width of the first element consistent